Find the segment $NQ$, in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$, in the circle below
In the figure, if $CN = a$, $NH = b$ and $HQ = c$. Calculate $NQ$
if $F$, $N$, $Q$ and $P$ are points of tangency.
(Answer: $c.\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}$)

I try:
$J = CA \cap \odot(O_1,O_1F) \neq F$
note that $\triangle JFO_1 \sim \triangle AFO$
because both are isosceles and $\angle JFO_1 = \angle AFO$
Soon, $JO_1 \parallel AO$
By the death star lemma, $F$, $B$, $N$ is are aligned and then
$\triangle O_1FN \sim \triangle OFB \implies O_1N \parallel OB \implies J, O_1$
Therefore $J$, $O_1$ and $N$ are collinear and $JN$ is the diameter of the smaller circle.
$CF = CQ$
$OF=OQ = OB$


@LionHeart sorry, There was an error in the translator...I've already corrected it. Thanks for alert

It looks like you done the shape yourself. A few parts are not clear, for example is $[CH] \perp [AB]$?

@adzetto Sorry, corrected

Note first of all that from the similarity $CFN\sim CHA$ one gets:
$$
CF:CN=CH:CA
$$
whence:
$$
CQ^2=CA\cdot CF=CN\cdot CH=a(a+b).
$$
Let $\gamma=\angle HCQ$. From the cosine rule applied to $CHQ$ one gets:
$$
2CQ\cos\gamma={a(a+b)+(a+b)^2-c^2\over (a+b)}=2a+{b}-{c^2\over a+b}
$$
and finally, from the cosine rule applied to $CNQ$ we obtain:
$$
NQ^2=a(a+b)+a^2-a\cdot 2CQ\cos\gamma.
$$
Subsitute here the preceding equality to get
$$
NQ^2={ac^2\over a+b}.
$$

Excellent my friend.thanks for help
